# calculate mean and gradient of the a certain number of rows before a timestamp in another datset

Tags: r

I have two datasets(db.temp, db.trans). Each one has time stamps and monitored environmental data.  **db.temp** has a shorter sampling interval (roughly every one minute), while **db.trans** has 50 min intervals.

Now I would like to calculate the mean value of db.temp (db.temp$WT) by averaging data within 15 minutes (not necessary 15 points because some data might be missing) prior to each timestamp in db.trans, and then append the **mean** as a new column to db.trans.  I also want to calculate the gradient (changing slop) of those data points using linear regression for each timestamp in db.trans, and then append it to db.trans.

I have a way to use if loop, but my dataset requires a much efficient approach.

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2016-10-02 07:00:21", "%Y-%m-%d %H: %M:%S",tz="")    
end <- as.POSIXct("2016-11-06 23:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="")    
start1 <- as.POSIXct("2016-10-05 17:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H: %M:%S",tz='')    
end1 <- as.POSIXct("2016-11-04 20:10:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="")

Temp.time<- seq(start, end, by =60)    
Temp.v <-runif (length(Temp.time),min=20, max=40)    
Trans.time <- seq (start1,end1, by=3000)    
Trans.v <-sample(state.name,length(Trans.time), replace = T)    
Trans.t <- runif(length(Trans.time), min=10, max=26)

db.temp <- data.frame(Time=Temp.time, WT=Temp.v)    
db.trans <- data.frame(Time=Trans.time,state=Trans.v, outT=Trans.t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the rolling join function from the `data.table` package should be useful here:

**Prepare the data**

```
library(data.table)

# convert both data frames to data.table
# (this is done by reference, for greater efficiency on large datasets)
setDT(db.temp)
setDT(db.trans)

# to avoid confusion, rename time column in db.temp
setnames(db.temp, "Time", "temp.Time")

# duplicate columns to be used for rolling join
db.temp[, join_time := temp.Time]
db.trans[, join_time := Time]

# set keys for join
setkey(db.temp, join_time)
setkey(db.trans, join_time)
```

**Join the data**

```
# join datasets by matching each db.temp row to the first db.trans row that comes after it
db.trans2 <- db.trans[db.temp, roll = -Inf]

# calculate time difference between the time stamps
db.trans2[, diff.time := as.numeric(difftime(Time, temp.Time, units = "mins"))]

# filter out db.temp rows that had no matching db.trans row (i.e. they took place entirely 
# after the last time stamp in the db.trans dataset)
# also filter for rows where the difference between db.temp & db.trans time stamps is 
# 15 min or less
db.trans2 <- db.trans2[!is.na(Time) & diff.time <= 15]
```

**Calculate**

```
# for each db.trans time stamp, calculate the mean / gradient of db.temp WT values
db.trans3 <- db.trans2[, list(mean.WT = mean(WT),
                              slope.WT = lm(WT ~ temp.Time)$coefficients[[2]]), 
                       by = list(Time, state, outT)]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, Z.Lin. It is exactly what I am looking for.  My following question is how to handle missed NA data. The last line of code gives me an error when I add NAs to my dataset: db.temp[4936:4950,2] <- NA.               Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases

Comment: Just realized that the slope shows NA when I used diff.time <=5. Not sure what happened. Thank you in advance.